# Algebraic closure and some basic fact

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $T$ be a transcendental basis of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q.$

**Definition**.  $\bar{\Bbb Q}(S)$ denotes an algebraic closure of $\bar{\Bbb Q}(S)$ in $\Bbb R$, that is, $\bar{\Bbb Q}(S)$ is the set of $x\in\Bbb R$ that are algebraic over $\Bbb Q(S).$

> Is this definition okay? Is there any book that has such a definition?

> Let $x\in\Bbb R$, then there exists $S\subset T$ such that $x\in\bar{\Bbb Q}(S)$? Is that right?

Any help would be appreciated greatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **first part**: $\mathbb{Q}(S)\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a field extension. So you can consider the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and call it $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(S)}$.

The **2nd part** seems fine as: Given $x\in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies a polynomial with coefficients in the field $\mathbb{Q}(T).$ Now the coefficients of the polynomial are fractions of polynomials in $T$.  Consider the set $S$ of all the elements of $T$ appearing in the polynomial. Now $x$ satisfies a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(S)$.

Comment: Evans Gambit. Thank you for your answer. Does the following true. For each  $m\in\Bbb R$, there exists with $x\in\Bbb R$ with $x\not\in\bar{\Bbb Q}(S)$ whenever $S$ has cardinality $\leq m$

Comment: @00GB You mean $m$ is a natural number, right?

Comment: Evans Gambit, yes

Comment: @00GB In that case $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(S)}$ is atmost countable. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, there will be $x\in \mathbb{R}$ not in the algebraic closure.

Comment: Evans Gambit. I see you are right

Comment: Evans Gambit, I have a short argument related to this. Do you mind if show this to you ?

Comment: @00GB ok, sure.

Comment: can I invite you to the chat?

Comment: @00GB you can post it in the comment.

Comment: I am writting now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128305/discussion-between-00gb-and-evans-gambit).

Comment: Did you see my short argument in the chat ?

Comment: Evans Gambit, Your $S$ in the answer for the second question is finite. Right?

Comment: Yes, S is finite.

Comment: Evans Gambit, thank you , did you see my last comment in another question when $| T\setminus  E|$ is infinit? . Thanks again

Comment: Evans Gambit , do you recommend any book that has more details about algebraic closure and transcendental basis? Since most of the books that I know, they do not give a lot of information about these topics.